Error while creating a new react app using npx create-react-app
First I'm facing an issue while creating a new app using npx create-react-app. Then I clear the cache by npm cache clean --force command. Now I'm facing the error:

npm error code TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE
npm error TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format

I have tried with completely uninstall and reinstall nodejs and npm. I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS.
Please help.
Thanks

CRA (create-react-app) is deprecated while ago, should go with create-vite

In my case i was using dockerfile to build and i had the same issue TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
I have just added this:
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global
before
npm install
it worked for me :)
